# How to force reboot EC2 instance after AWS CloudFormation finished running?

Tags: windows, amazon-cloudformation

I've created a CF template for installing Windows 2012 R2 server with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It executed w/o errors but when I tried to run Visual Studio it said "reboot pending" but server never rebooted itself. Is it possible to give a hint to the server in CF template to actually reboot itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` and reference it in your Windows instance. Inside this you should be able to call something like `shutdown.exe /r /t 00` from it. The only access you have to the box within Cloud Formation is within this `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` step.